# WebSphere Portal 6.1.5 Feature Pack

Tags: websphere

Has anyone had problems upgrading WebSphere Portal 6.1.0.1/WebSphere Portal 6.1.5.3 Feature Pack.

On IBM i V7.1

Answer (score 0):

You made a pretty vague question... However, consider the following: how high quality have the IBM updates been in the past? Yes, that's right. They might skin your cat, drink all your beer and rape your girlfriend while they spew out errors just for the heck of it.

To give you something more concrete and specific to 6.1->6.1.5 update: The 6.1.5 will add new libraries to the global classpath of your application server. One such library is Rome (the RSS parsing library). If any of your applications are using Rome then you should be prepared to change the classloader settings to "application first".

Other than that the 6.1.5 update should be more or less uneventful.